# how to access and manipulate pdf file's datas in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoopy

I want to read the PDF file using hadoop, how it is possible?
I only know that hadoop can process only txt files, so is there anyway to parse the PDF files to txt.

Give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to create a [SequenceFile](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html) to contain the PDF files. SequenceFile is a binary file format. You could make each record in the SequenceFile a PDF. To do this you would create a class derived from [Writable](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) which would contain the PDF and any metadata that you needed. Then you could use any java PDF library such as [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to manipulate the PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Processing PDF files in Hadoop can be done by extending [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) Class. Let the class extending it be WholeFileInputFormat. In the WholeFileInputFormat class you override the getRecordReader() method. Now each pdf will be received as an **Individual Input Split**. Then these **individual splits** can be parsed to extract the text.  This [link](http://codedemigod.com/blog/?p=120) gives a clear example of understanding how to extend FileInputFormat.