# How to parse PDF files in map reduce programs?

Tags: java, pdf, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to parse PDF files in my hadoop 2.2.0 program and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9443671/1805756), followed what it says and until now, I have these three classes:

1. **`PDFWordCount`:** the main class containing map and reduce functions. (just like [native hadoop wordcount](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) sample but instead of `TextInputFormat` I used my `PDFInputFormat` class.
2. **`PDFRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>`:** Which is the main work here. Especially I put my `initialize` function here for more illustration.

   ```
   public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
         throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         System.out.println("initialize");
         System.out.println(genericSplit.toString());
       FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
       System.out.println("filesplit convertion has been done");
       final Path file = split.getPath();
       Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
       conf.getInt("mapred.linerecordreader.maxlength", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
       FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
       System.out.println("fs has been opened");
       start = split.getStart();
       end = start + split.getLength();
       System.out.println("going to open split");
       FSDataInputStream filein = fs.open(split.getPath());
       System.out.println("going to load pdf");
       PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(filein);
       System.out.println("pdf has been loaded");
       PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       in =
       new LineReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(stripper.getText(pd).getBytes(
           "UTF-8")));
       start = 0;
       this.pos = start;
       System.out.println("init has finished");
     }
   ```

   (You can see my `system.out.println`s for debugging.
   This method fails in converting `genericSplit` to `FileSplit`. Last thing I see in console, is this:

   ```
   hdfs://localhost:9000/in:0+9396432
   ```

   which is `genericSplit.toString()`
3. **`PDFInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>`:** which just creates  `new PDFRecordReader` in `createRecordReader` method.

I want to know what is my mistake?

Do I need extra classes or something?

Comment: Don't you have some logs? Please add a Stacktrace.

Comment: No, there is no `Exception`. It just terminates there.

Comment: That is highly unlikely, not even in your tasklogs?;-)

Comment: Where should I check for tasklogs? (I am running this in eclipse.)

Runnin this project in eclipse does not make any files in `hadoop/logs/...`.

Comment: okay, either try to add a print statement like `System.out.println(genericSplit.getClass())` or hang in a debugger. Are you submitting the job to a running cluster? If yes, then there must be some logs.

Comment: I don't know any way to debug the map reduce programs. If you know any, plz help me in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20758069/1805756). I have a single node setup of hadoop on localhost and I run my tests on it.

Comment: Just add `mapreduce.jobtracker.address`=`local` to your configuration, it will run in the same JVM for debugging.

Comment: Sorry, would you please tell me where to add this configuration? Do you mean hadoop configurations in hadoop/etc/hadoop/ files or eclipse config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading PDFs is not that difficult, you need to extend the class FileInputFormat as well as the RecordReader. The FileInputClass should not be able to split PDF files since they are binaries.

```
public class PDFInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
    TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return new PDFLineRecordReader();
  }

  // Do not allow to ever split PDF files, even if larger than HDFS block size
  @Override
  protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

The RecordReader then performs the reading itself (I am using PDFBox to read PDFs).

```
public class PDFLineRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, Text> {

private Text key = new Text();
private Text value = new Text();
private int currentLine = 0;
private List<String> lines = null;

private PDDocument doc = null;
private PDFTextStripper textStripper = null;

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
    final Path file = fileSplit.getPath();

    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
    FSDataInputStream filein = fs.open(fileSplit.getPath());

    if (filein != null) {

        doc = PDDocument.load(filein);

        // Konnte das PDF gelesen werden?
        if (doc != null) {
            textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String text = textStripper.getText(doc);

            lines = Arrays.asList(text.split(System.lineSeparator()));
            currentLine = 0;

        }

    }
}

    // False ends the reading process
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if (key == null) {
        key = new Text();
    }

    if (value == null) {
        value = new Text();
    }

    if (currentLine < lines.size()) {
        String line = lines.get(currentLine);

        key.set(line);

        value.set("");
        currentLine++;

        return true;
    } else {

        // All lines are read? -> end
        key = null;
        value = null;
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return key;
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return value;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return (100.0f / lines.size() * currentLine) / 100.0f;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {

    // If done close the doc
    if (doc != null) {
        doc.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sidd.hadoop.practice.pdf;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import com.sidd.hadoop.practice.input.pdf.PdfFileInputFormat;
import com.sidd.hadoop.practice.output.pdf.PdfFileOutputFormat;

public class ReadPdfFile {

    public static class MyMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
//          context.progress();
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends
            Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
        public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (values.iterator().hasNext()) {
                context.write(key, values.iterator().next());
            } else {
                context.write(key, new Text(""));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Read Pdf");
        job.setJarByClass(ReadPdfFile.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(PdfFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(PdfFileOutputFormat.class);

        removeDir(args[1], conf);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void removeDir(String path, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        Path output_path = new Path(path);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if (fs.exists(output_path)) {
            fs.delete(output_path, true);
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Though your code may be the answer to the question, it would be better to provide more info about it like why you chose this approach etc.