# Java MapReduce program to work on PDF files

Tags: java, pdf, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I need to parse PDF file in a mapreduce program using Java. I am on a cluster setup using CDH 5.0.1. I have a custom Input Format class extended by FileInputFormat where I have overridden getRecordReader method to return an instance of a custom RecordReader, and isSplitable method to prevent the file to be non-splittable as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626671/420544).

Now the problem is, in the current CDH API getRecordReader returns Interface org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader while the one extended to custom Record Reader in the above SO answer, is an abstract class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader.

My custom Input Format class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;

public class PDFInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

@Override
public RecordReader<Text, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf conf, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    return new PDFRecordReader();
    }

@Override
protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
    return false;
    }

}
```

Appreciate any help or pointers as to what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the wrong api(old `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*`api)
Please use the new API (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`)

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
```

The SO answer you following using this new API. In new API `RecordReader` is `class` not `interface`

**UPDATE**

[mapred vs mapreduce API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269922/hadoop-mapred-vs-hadoop-mapreduce)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if I use the suggested API the FileInputFormat does not have a getRecordReader method rather it has a createRecordReader.

Comment: Also, I can see both the classes available in the same API i.e. CDH 5.0.1 - Hadoop 2.3.0 without any of the one listed as deprecated.
Here, I have given the links to both the classes for the same API.
[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html)
[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html)

Comment: you are correct the old api is not depricated yet, to support legacy code.If you are doing a new code I suggest to use new API implementaions. to find the difference please see the update in answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help but in that case, how do I support overriding getRecordReader method which is not present in the new API.

Comment: you don't need that method. createRecordReader is the replacement for that in new API.I once did that for my case: https://github.com/thomachan/Custom-MR/blob/master/src/mapreduce/hi/api/input/CustomInputFormat.java