# Undesired output from Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to process four lines of a data-set together. I have used a variable *lineCount* in the mapper for this. But am not getting some part of the outputs correctly.

Here is my mapper class:-

```
public class GC_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    int lineCount = 0;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        if (lineCount % 4 == 0) {
            context.write(new Text("#Reads"), new IntWritable(1));
            lineCount++;
            return;
        }

        if (lineCount % 4 == 1) {
            context.write(new Text("X"), new IntWritable(1));               
            lineCount++;
            return;
        }

        if (lineCount % 4 == 2) {
            context.write(new Text("Y"), new IntWritable(1));
            lineCount++;
            return;
        }

        if (lineCount % 4 == 3) {
            context.write(new Text("Z"), new IntWritable(1));
            lineCount++;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My Reducer :-

```
public class GC_Reducer extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
    int numReads;

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if ((key.toString()).startsWith("#")) {
            for (IntWritable read : values) {
                numReads += read.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(numReads));
        }

        if ((key.toString().startsWith("X"))) {
            double sum1 = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum1 += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(sum1));
        }

        if ((key.toString().startsWith("Y"))) {
            double sum2 = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum2 += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(sum2));
        }

        if ((key.toString().startsWith("Z"))) {
            double sum3 = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum3 += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(sum3));
        }
    }
}
```

My intention was to take the number of Reads(provided 4 lines are taken as a single record) and to process four lines differently. 
But the problem am facing that I got the output as :-

```
#Reads 50.0
X      100.0
Y      100.0
Z      100.0
```

But my desired output was 50.0 for all the keys. Only #Reads value is correct. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is your input? And why are you using a double variable when the input is IntWritable

Comment: My input is a sequence file where one sequence is consisted of four lines. And i want to process four lines differently. This is a sample program. Actual processing is not included. I just outputted the count of each line.

Comment: Leave all about the output value type. Again if i provided Intwritable,output will be the same

Comment: How about defining all the variables in reduce part as global similar to numReads

Comment: I don't think that will make any difference.

Comment: Then how do you justify that only the first field has got correct output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72200/discussion-between-sachin-and-jijo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by my selves. It was a mistake from my part actually. My mapper output value was *IntWritable*. And i tried to assign it to a double variable and tried to write that value as *DoubleWritable* in the reducer. Thanks all !

Answer (score 1):

If all your data is in 4-line-record format, then it sounds better to work with `FileInputFormat` as well as the `RecordReader`. You just need to send 4 lines of text file together to a mapper, not send it line by line.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626671/1805756) answer to my question about reading pdfs in hadoop. Your main work will rely on `nextKeyValue` function of your `RecordReader` extended class.